# God monitoring: Delay start after process exit

Tags: ruby, god

I am monitoring a ruby program with god. When the ruby program exits, I want to wait for 10 seconds until it is started again. When I use `grace`, after the process exits, the process is immediately started again, but god waits for the grace period of 10 seconds until it looks at the process. When the process is now killed before the grace is over, god won't pick it up again and the process is never restarted.

I would like god to wait for 10 seconds until the start command is run after an exit. How would I do that?

I tried with `transition` on `:process_exits` in the watch, but I have difficulties finding a way to set the wait time at the right spot.

**EDIT:** After looking through the sources of god, I suspect, that a possible solution is to add a custom behavior which waits in its `before_start` method. Does that sound reasonable? (See below) (END)

---

More details:

When I use the `grace` features in a `watch`, I get this behaviour:

```
 INFO: Loading simple.god
 INFO: Syslog enabled.
 INFO: Using pid file directory: /Users/fsc/.god/pids
 INFO: Started on drbunix:///tmp/god.17165.sock
 INFO: simple_god move 'unmonitored' to 'init'
DEBUG: driver schedule #<God::Conditions::ProcessRunning:0x007fe134dee140> in 0 seconds
 INFO: simple_god moved 'unmonitored' to 'init'
 INFO: simple_god [trigger] process is not running (ProcessRunning)
DEBUG: simple_god ProcessRunning [false] {true=>:up, false=>:start}
 INFO: simple_god move 'init' to 'start'
 INFO: simple_god start: ruby .../simple.rb
DEBUG: driver schedule #<God::Conditions::ProcessRunning:0x007fe134dedb00> in 0 seconds
 INFO: simple_god moved 'init' to 'start'
 INFO: simple_god [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
DEBUG: simple_god ProcessRunning [true] {true=>:up}
 INFO: simple_god move 'start' to 'up'
 INFO: simple_god registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 42498
 INFO: simple_god moved 'start' to 'up'
```

Here I kill the process.

```
 INFO: simple_god [trigger] process 42498 exited (ProcessExits)
DEBUG: simple_god ProcessExits [true] {true=>:start}
 INFO: simple_god move 'up' to 'start'
 INFO: simple_god deregistered 'proc_exit' event for pid 42498
 INFO: simple_god start: ruby .../simple.rb
```

Here the grace period kicks in. At this point the process is already started. However, the god watch waits for the grace period until it looks at the process.

The next log line occurs 10 seconds (the grace) after the last log line from above:

```
DEBUG: driver schedule #<God::Conditions::ProcessRunning:0x007fe134dedb00> in 0 seconds
 INFO: simple_god moved 'up' to 'start'
 INFO: simple_god [trigger] process is running (ProcessRunning)
DEBUG: simple_god ProcessRunning [true] {true=>:up}
 INFO: simple_god move 'start' to 'up'
 INFO: simple_god registered 'proc_exit' event for pid 42501
 INFO: simple_god moved 'start' to 'up'
```

---

**EDIT:**

The custom behavior:

```
module God
  module Behaviors

    class WaitBehavior < Behavior
      attr_accessor :delay

      def initialize
        super
        self.delay = 10
      end

      def valid?
        valid = true
        valid
      end

      def before_start
        if delay>0 then
          sleep delay
        end
      end

      def test
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using the behavior in the .god config:

```
w.behavior(:wait_behavior)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work, and the `WaitBehavior` class could be shorter.

```
module God
  module Behaviors
    class WaitBehavior < Behavior
      attr_accessor :delay

      def before_start
        sleep delay.to_i if delay.to_i > 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in .god config:

```
# .god
w.behavior(:wait_behavior) do |b|
  b.delay = 10
end
```

#### another way

Similar to `WaitBehavior`, we can define a `StateFileBehavior` to touch a file after_stop.

```
require 'fileutils'

module God
  module Behaviors
    class StateFileBehavior < Behavior
      attr_accessor :file

      def after_stop
        FileUtils.touch file
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in `.god` config

```
# .god
stop_timestamp_file = '/path/to/file'

w.behavior(:state_file_behavior) do |b|
  b.file = stop_timestamp_file
end

w.start_if do |on|
  on.condition(:file_mtime) do |c|
    c.interval = 2
    c.path = stop_timestamp_file
    c.max_age = 10
  end
end
```

*Notice: In the second way, it could not work fine with `w.keepalive`*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the "file way". Regarding the `keepalive`: I assume that it would not work, because in `keepalive` for the transition from `:up` to `:start` the `process_exits` condition will be `true` and the internal logic moves on if any condition is true? (So it doesn't care about the `:file_mtime` condition)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, both solutions work but you can also do it without modifying god by using lambda conditions. I just created a new `:down` state, when the process exits I will make a transition to the `:down` state and then using a lambda delay the start for some time.

To create the new state you just need to add it to the valid_states

This is how my god file looks like

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = "brain"
  w.start = "ruby yourthing.rb"
  w.stop_grace = 30
  w.valid_states = [:init, :up, :start, :restart, :down]
...

  # down if process not running
  w.transition(:up, :down) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_exits) 
  end

  # delay when down and move to start
  w.transition(:down, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:lambda) do |c|
      c.lambda = lambda do
        puts "process exists, sleep 30 seconds"
        sleep 30
        true
      end
    end
  end
```